# Average bits/s report in tshark

Tags: wireshark

Does tshark has an option to report average bit/s statistics of the capture which appear in Wireshark at the end of Statistics > Capture File Properties?

I'm trying to automate a load test and need this in command line rather than GUI. I'm going through the tshark man page and it looks like `-z io,stat,interval,"COUNT|SUM|MIN|MAX|AVG|LOAD(field)filter"` option does not have it, does it?

Answer (score 1):

I think TShark does not provide such option. You may try to use [capinfos](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/capinfos.html) instead.

Comment: More specifically, `capinfos -i <file>` displays just the bitrate. `capinfos -A <file>` shows all information, including the bitrate.